# How to filter nested union in rti dds

Tags: filter, data-distribution-service

I have a data type as

```
enum T1 {
    A,
    B
};

enum T2 {
    C,
    D
};

union T3 switch(T1) {
case A:  
    uint8 x;
case B:
    uint8 y;
};

union T4 switch(T2) {
case C:
    uint8 a;
case D:
    T3 b;
};
```

Use T4 as data type.
Does a method exist to filter b.x ＞ 10   in rti dds content filter topic ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated！